# Mail server name keeps changing

Tags: mac-osx, email-server

I have a server running Snow Leopard and I'm having an issue with mail. Occasionally (and seemingly without reason) the mail server's domain and host names change to "local" and when this happens, no one can send mail and any mail received is lost. Any idea what is causing this change?

[image]

At worst, I'll change permissions to prevent the mail configuration files from changing, but this will make it annoying to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Take a look here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2235366?start=0&tstart=0).

Seems that this behavior can be a result of OSX not being able to resolve its FQDN from its assigned DNS servers.  So, check to make sure you have a working DNS entry for whatever you want the server's name to be in whatever DNS servers you're using on this server.